# CSS for custom checkbox and custom radio box

Tags: html, css, mobile, checkbox, radio-button

I have implemented the custom checkbox and radio box like this

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqfty04x/

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #AD7471;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 16px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2713";
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #AD7471;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is , the dot inside radio box and the tick inside the checkbox is not vertical align center, it works fine on desktop but on mobile it goes down,

have spent some time on it and suspect it is due to the line-height, it does not stable and can't find a number that suitable for all case

How to fix it? jsfiddle is provided, feel free to play around it.

Thanks

Comment: `line-height` == `height` ... https://jsfiddle.net/Lqfty04x/1/

Comment: good try. but the checkbox is not veritcal align center. Also, the radio button 's dot seems isn't horizontal align  (slightly right). would you mind take a look

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqfty04x/2/ ... Just change the line-height for checkbox too, "seems" missaligned but it's centered

Comment: @DaniP You should post that as an answer.

Comment: That's the tricky part of using "content" for elements like this, the font will change between devices and viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use web font icons such as Font Awesome over the standard unicode characters, so that it gives you a consistent results across different browsers and devices.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px 4px;
}
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + span:before,
input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
}
input[type="radio"] + span:before {
  content: "\f1db";
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f192";
}
input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "\f096";
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
  content: "\f046";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" checked> <span>Radio 1</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="test"> <span>Radio 2</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" checked> <span>Checkbox 1</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test"> <span>Checkbox 2</span>
</label>
```